# Flutter - iOS Tensorflow issues

Tags: flutter, tensorflow

I've built a Flutter app with facial recognition using Tensorflow, works great on Android but just cannot get the iOS version to build in xcode.
It cannot find the TensorFlow libraries not matter what I do.

Anyone else had any issues / got any suggestions please?

Regards
Col

Comment: Hi! Could you post your pubspec.yaml file here and post the error stack trace here.